# Automate sync via git between repo and server, ignoring but not removing files in .gitignore from source

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, version-control

I would like to push and pull from a GitHub repository in a slightly complicated setup.

**CMS/Server ⇄ GitHub ⇄ Translation Service**

I'm using a flat file CMS which stores content as `.txt` files, one per language: `*.en.txt`, `*.de.txt`, `*.es.txt`. It also stores the multimedia files in the same directories, `*.png`, `.mp4`, `*.jpg`, etc.

My `.gitignore` excludes all the media files from the repo as they are not relevant to the Translation Service.

The `*.txt` files need to be pushed to the GitHub repo when changes are made via the CMS. The Translation Service reads the `*.en.txt` files and deposits/updates the other language files (`*.en.txt`, `*.de.txt`, `*.es.txt`) once per 24hrs back into the repo. These then need to be pulled by the server back into the CMS, whilst not removing the files that aren't in the repo, like multimedia files.

I would like to script and automate the push/pull process between the server/CMS and the GitHub repo making sure that the media files are not removed from the server/CMS when fetching/pulling from the repo, even though they are not in the repo.

I'm currently handling this process manually. Could someone outline the approach that one might use to set this relationship up to be automated?

Let me know if you need any more information.